# UIPickerView modal with already visible toolbar attached

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

(See Sketch)

How would I implement this behaviour with an already visible toolbar? Also, the little information I found on opening a UIPicker modal are all based on using a UITextField which is not what I'm aiming for.

What I'm looking for is a button on the toolbar opening the picker modal with the toolbar attached to it. Button1 on the sketch is simply to select a value the user is most likely to pick (Something like "Go to todays date"), and done should hide the modal and bring the toolbar back to it's original state of being attached to the bottom of the screen.

Ideally, I'd like this toolbar with the picker functionality to be avaiable on multiple views.

[image: Sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add constraints to your storyboard, connect them as outlets to your code and then disable and enable the appropriate ones whenever needed.

One constraint setup would be:

- add a constraint that pins the top of the picker to the bottom of the view
- add another constraint pinning the bottom of the picker to the bottom of the view

> -> If you enable 1 and disable 2, the picker is hidden
>   -> If you enable 2 and disable 1, the picker is visible

That change in constraints is animateable which will result in a smooth UI change.

Comment: Excellent idea, however how could I use this without having to define the same UI elements for multiple views in my Storyboard? Like I mentioned, ideally I'd need this functionality to be avaibale in multiple (2 at the moment) views.

Comment: @Marv Hmmm, what you can do is extract the entire toolbar or just the picker into a different view+controller which then communicates via delegation with the parent but is itself responsible for the animation and constraints. You can then include that view+controller via a `container view` (`UIContainerView`) everywhere you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works out just fine. Is there a guideline for animation length or do you by chance know the animation duration of the default picker modal slide when you tap a textfield?

Comment: @Marv Unfortunately I do not know what the default animation duration is - I would just play around with the values until they seem to fit, maybe even use different timing functions.